# How can I call geoLocation in componentDidMount in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I was trying to use axios to pull up an api along with HTML5Geolocation.

I place it inside the componentDidMount and was expecting it to work atleast console.log the result using async and eventually set the state to the country.

```
componentDidMount(){
    async onLoad() {
        if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
           window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
           position => {
              const response = axios.get('http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode' , {
                   lat: position.coords.latitude,
                   lng: position.coords.longitude,
                   type: 'JSON'
               });
               console.log('here is the response >>>>', response.countryName); 
               this.setState({ country: response.countryName })
           });

           }
         }

}
```

However this is currently not working. I am using [Geonames](https://www.geonames.org/) for my API

Any idea what am I doing wrong on my code?

Comment: What challenge you are facing exactly ? does this code errors ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Shridhar Sharma remove the onLoad.

You're missing the `await` in your code. Without it the await expression, the execution of the async function wont wait for the Promise resolution.

One more thing to keep in mind, even if the browser supports geolocation there could be other errors such as PERMISSION_DENIED, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE and TIMEOUT. See more

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError/code

```
componentDidMount() {
        if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
            window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( async (position) => {
                const response = await axios.get("http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode", {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude,
                    type: "JSON"
                });
                console.log("here is the response >>>>", response.countryName);
                this.setState({ country: response.countryName });

            }, (e) => {
                // other errors appear here
                console.log(e);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("navigator not supported");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the `onLoad` method but not calling it, remove the declaration and call the code directly because it makes no sense to declare a method inside `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const response = axios.get('http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode', {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude,
          type: 'JSON'
        });
        console.log('here is the response >>>>', response.countryName);
        this.setState({
          country: response.countryName
        })
      });
  }
}
```